# New role in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles, user-roles

I searched and searched and searched and could not find the answer.

My Question: For a project we need to implement a new customer role in WooCommerce. By default WooCommerce offers the roles "Customer" and "Shop Manager". We would need something like "Premium Customer". The setup of the capabilities for this new role is not a problem for us.

We would greatly appreciate any hints or tips in the right direction. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try a plugin at http://www.ladadeal.com/user-roles-for-woocommerce

With User Roles for Woocommerce plugin you can change user role for every customer.
Add new roles and customize its capabilities according to your needs, from scratch of as a copy of other existing role.
Unnecessary self-made role can be deleted if there are no users whom such role is assigned. Assign new role for Customer when by product, by category, etc..
Role assigned every new created user by default may be changed too.
FEATURE:

Capabilities could be assigned on per user basis. Multiple roles could be assigned to user simultaneously.
Multi-store support is provided.
Hide selected front-end menu items for no logged-in visitors, logged-in users, roles.
Block selected widgets under “Appearance” menu for role.
Show widgets at front-end for selected roles.
Roles and Users permissions management via Network Admin for multisite configuration. One click Synchronization to the whole network.
Manage user access to editing posts/pages/custom post type using posts/pages, authors, taxonomies ID list.
Per plugin users access management for plugins activate/deactivate operations.
Shortcode to show enclosed content to the users with selected roles only.
Posts and pages view restrictions for selected roles.﻿

Answer (score 0):

I guess, didn´t try, you can use this plugin for that: http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/custom-woocommerce-roles-admin-capabilities/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the wordpress function add_role??

Something like this will do the job:

```
add_role('premium_customer', 'Premium Customer', array(
    'read' => true, 
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false, 
));
```

Just add this to your theme functions.